# PublishingRolloutImage not persisting on Update();

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a list, that has three fields: Title, PublishingRollupImage and Description.

I want to upload the image to the library **SiteCollectionImages** and reference it on the list.

I'm able to upload the file to the folder SiteCollectionImages, and get it's url.

I'm also able to insert the item in the list "MyList", but the PublishingRolloutImage won't persist after the Update() method. I already tried to set the constructor for the ImageFieldValue, like this:

```
        new ImageFieldValue("<img src='test.jpg' />");
```

but it didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
        using (var site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
        using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            var folder = web.GetFolder("SiteCollectionImages");
            var file = folder.Files.Add(fileName, file, true);
            folder.Update();

            var list = web.Lists["MyList"];
            var item = list.Items.Add();
            item["Title"] = "MyItemTitle";
            item["PublishingRollupImage"] = new ImageFieldValue { ImageUrl = file.Url };
            item["Description"] = "MyDescription";
            item.Update();
        }
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, i found out that i was doing two things wrong:

this:

```
item["PublishingRollupImage"] = new ImageFieldValue { ImageUrl = file.Url };
```

was supposed to be like this:

```
var image = item["PublishingRollupImage"] as ImageFieldValue ?? new ImageFieldValue();
image.ImageUrl = String.Format("/{0}", file.Url);
item["PublishingRollupImage"] = image;
```

and **file.Url** needs to start with a slash. If it doesn't start with a slash, it will break after the Update(); method. That's the reason for the String.Format up there.